# a set of images with a slide show - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, web

I would like to make a slide show for several images on the website while I encounter a problem when trying to copy the script or create a new function under a different name to light the next image on the page. Then you can not see either both photos on the page or you can see only one. I'm new to JS, I just want to do some pictures under me so that every image changes to another every 2 seconds, I need it for a website.

Regards

Here is orignal code:
https://jsfiddle.net/bradtraversy/74owmd01/

My problem JS:

```
var i = 0;          // Start Point
var images = [];    // Images Array
var time = 3000;    // Time Between Switch

// Image List
images[0] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals";
images[1] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports";
images[2] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food";
images[3] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people";

// Change Image
function changeImg(){
    document.slide_1.src = images[i];

    // Check If Index Is Under Max
    if(i < images.length - 1){
      // Add 1 to Index
      i++; 
    } else { 
        // Reset Back To O
        i = 0;
    }

  function changeImg_2(){
    document.slide_2.src = images[i];

    // Check If Index Is Under Max
    if(i < images.length - 1){
      // Add 1 to Index
      i++; 
    } else { 
        // Reset Back To O
        i = 0;
    }


    // Run function every x seconds
    setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
  setTimeout("changeImg_2()", time);
}

// Run function when page loads
window.onload=changeImg;
```

HTML:

```
<img name="slide_1" width="400" height="200" />
<img name="slide_2" width="400" height="200" />
```

Comment: What is the issue? Do you have an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please update your code.

```
var i = 0;          // Start Point
var images = [];    // Images Array
var time = 5000;    // Time Between Switch

// Image List
images[0] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals";
images[1] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports";
images[2] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food";
images[3] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people";

// Change Image
function changeImg(){
document.slide.src = images[i];
  i++;
  if(i>=images.length)
    i=0;

}
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(changeImg, time);
});
```